# Get contents of a site behind cloudflare in c#

Tags: c#, cloudflare

I want to get contents of a site that is behind cloudflare
I use

```
WebClient webcl = new WebClient();
string content = webcl.DownloadString("http://example.com");
```

But it doesn't work
It only shows the code that is for cloudflare and don't contain the site contents

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_? You get any exception or error message? Can you please be more specific about your problem?

Comment: You may have to set the user agent value in order to get a valid response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudFlare appears to be blocking you for whatever reason. In order to get around this you need to [whitelist your C# server in CloudFlare itself](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171266-How-do-I-block-blacklist-or-trust-whitelist-visitors-by-IP-) or add a subdomain which doesn't go through CloudFlare. In the event your IP is changing, you either need to whitelist through the CloudFlare API or just route through a proxy with a static IP.